# How do I parse more than 2 argument in my URL Path function in Django

Tags: django

Please Assist me.

I have this in my url Pattern of my blog app

```
app_name = 'webpages'

 path('articles/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>', views.blog_detail, name='articles_detail'),
```

How do I code this in the template? I have tried this

```
<a href="{% url 'webpages:articles_detail' post.pk post.slug %}">{{post.title}}</a>
```

I was able to do this for just one argument. but ran into trouble doing for two arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use kwargs-like syntax:

```html
<a href="{% url 'webpages:articles_detail' pk=post.pk slug=post.slug %}">{{post.title}}</a>
```

Full example:

.../some_app/views.py

```py
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse


def some_view(request):
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'some_app/some_template.html')


def another_view(request, first_arg, second_arg):
    return TemplateResponse(
        request, 'some_app/another_template.html',
        context={'first_arg': first_arg, 'second_arg': second_arg}
    )
```

.../some_app/templates/some_app/some_template.html

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1><a href={% url 'another_view' first_arg=1 second_arg=2 %}>Click here to go to another_view </a></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

.../some_app/templates/some_app/another_template.html

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ first_arg }} | {{ second_arg }}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

.../some_app/urls.py

```py
# ...
urlpatterns = [
    path('some_view/', some_view),
    path('another_view/<int:first_arg>/<int:second_arg>/', another_view, name='another_view')
]
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have it sorted. Apparently there were some other broken links that I was not paying attention to. the pattern I posted works.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting? That code should work fine. I do something similar in my code and it is working fine

```
<a href="{% url matchUrl matchFilter object.id %}">{{object.name}}</a>
```

Here matchUrl is a context variable from the view and matchUrl/matchFilter/object.id points to a different view.

Comment: this is the error i get. 

NoReverseMatch at /articles/

Reverse for 'articles_detail' with arguments '(5,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['articles/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Comment: Thanks, I have it sorted. Apparently there were some other broken links that I was not paying attention to. the pattern I posted works.